# Relationship between G(k) and $\Gamma(k)$ in Waring's Problem

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I was reading the series of paper on Waring's problem, by Hardy and Littlewood, named "Partitio Numerorum".. I am new to some of their methods.. I was wondering if one knew $\Gamma(k)$ for some positive integer k , can one then calculate G(k)? What about the other way?

G(k) is the smallest 't' such that every large enough positive number is sum of at most t k-th power of positive integers. $\Gamma(k)$ is the least number 's' such that for any natural n, the equation $ x_{1}^{k} + x_{2}^{k}  + ... + x_{s} ^{k} =  n $ is solvable in each p-adic $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$.

May be I am being too naive here but may be when k is prime or prime power , this is possible? Need some expert help..

Comment: Going from solvable in each $\Bbb{Q}_p$ to solvable in $\Bbb{Q}$ is called the 
[local-global principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_principle) and when it holds it is quite non-trivial to prove it. For a fixed $k$, $\Gamma(k)$ is always "easily" computable in the sense that it reduces to finitely many cases to check (because for $p\nmid k, x\in \Bbb{Z}_p$ the binomial series implies $ (1+px)^{1/k}\in \Bbb{Z}_p$)

Comment: Well true as your comment may be, I am guessing Hardy-Littlewood were looking for $\Gamma(k)$ for some reason.. So far, all I could find is that G(k)$\geq\Gamma(k)$. They have another definition of $\Gamma (k)$ that was related to a certain quantity in their Singular series.. which later they showed that is same as the definition I gave. Since $\Gamma(k)$ appeared in singular series, I was thinking they can be related

Comment: Also i believe checking solutions in padics may be easy, but we need solution in each padic and more importantly, showing that whatever s one obtained is least, is not easy..

Comment: it is easy to check solutions in all $\Bbb{Q}_p$ not only one.

Comment: Sure.. but i would like to come back to my question.. perhaps someone with expertise in Hardy-Littlewood methods can give their two cents